# Unable to conect to my db when running docker, but i can connect without it

Tags: spring-boot, docker, hibernate

I'm new using docker, and java by the way. I made a chatroom and I have a mysql database working fine in planet scale. I can run my service correctly in localhost, but I want to deploy it, so I am trying to run docker. Here is where the problem start. I'm building the jar file, but when I try to run it, I'm getting the following error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
(..)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
(...)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
*

**This is my POM: **

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.chatserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chatserver</name>
    <description>Chat App Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
            <scope>provider</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>chatserver</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**And this my persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="chatserver" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.chatserver.chatserver.model.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://aws.connect.psdb.cloud/chatroomdb?sslMode=VERIFY_IDENTITY"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="10" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**This is the method I'm using to create the Entity Manager: **

```
    public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(){
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        Map<String, Object> configOverrides = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", env.get("CHATROOM_DB_USER"));
        configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", env.get("CHATROOM_DB_PASSWORD"));
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("chatserver", configOverrides);
    }
```

**And this is my Dockerfile: **

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY /target/chatserver.jar chatserver.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/chatserver.jar"]
```

I've been trying for days without finding a solution. If you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong, I would love to read it. Thanks!